# Is there a Vim 7.3 or 7.4 package available somewhere for CentOS 6.5

Tags: vim, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.5 and the only Vim packages available from yum are for Vim 7.2, even though Vim 7.4 is now out.  A lot of the Vim plugins I typically use are only compatible with Vim 7.3 and above.

Is there a way to get 7.3 or 7.4 as a package install from some third party rather than the official yum repo?

Comment: I'm just throwing this as a possible solution. Compiling vim from source isn't very hard if you already have all the required libraries already installed.

Comment: [Funny you ask…](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/21csbe/anyone_have_an_rpm_for_vim_74x_centos_6/)

Comment: @FDinoff, Yeah I did compile from source for the time being. While it isn't that hard it takes significantly longer to complete than a simple yum install. If this were just a one time install for myself that wouldn't be a big deal, but this is going on all our Vagrant VMs for each project so the extra time is compounded on 2 axis where 1 axis is number of developer and the other is number of projects.

Comment: If you've compiled from source already, can't you just make the compile directory accessible on all the machines and do a `make install` on each of them?

Comment: @Ben, sure I can put it on a file share or something. I'm really just surprised that there isn't a package for this already.  It's not like I'm asking for something cutting edge here. Vim 7.3 was released in August of 2010. I would have thought since it's been 3 and 1/2 years there would be a package available by now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this repo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/cathay4t:/misc-rhel6/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/ which has vim rpms. Worked for me on a rhel 6 host.
Link was found from this blog post http://cathay4t.blogspot.com/2014/09/compile-vim-7473-in-rhel-6.html